# laravel 5.4 the function return result with a blank page

Tags: laravel-5

I'm new to laravel and trying to make a search function then I'm having an issue where the code is returning a blank page & it suppose to return a table with results

this is the BookSearchController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use DB;
use App\Book_Search;

class BookSearchController extends Controller
{
   public function searchForm(){
        return view('book-search');
   }
   public function searchbook(Request $request){
        $reader = new Book_Search;
        $reader->searchbooks($request);
   }
}
```

this is the Book_Search model

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Http\Requests;
use DB;

class Book_Search extends Model
{

    public function searchbooks(Request $request){
        //$query = $request->all();
      $query = $request->get('query');
      $Books = DB::table('bookuser')->Join('users', 'bookuser.userID', '=','users.id')->Join('book', 'bookuser.bookID','=','book.ID')->select('Firstname','picture','price','availabilty','name')->where('name','like','%'. $query. '%')->get();
      return view('book_search', compact('Books', 'query'));
   }
}
```

the form that takes the query

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Book | Search</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action = "/searchingg" method = "post">
         <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value = "<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Name</td>
               <td><input type='text' name='query' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan = '2'>
                  <input type = 'submit' value = "search"/>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>   
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

the form that suppose to view the result

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Search Student Records</title>
   </head>

   <body>

      <table border = "1">
         <tr>
            <td>User Name</td>
            <td>Picture</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Availability</td>
             <td>Book Name</td>
         </tr>
         <?php
          foreach ($Books as $Book){
         ?>
         <tr>
            <td><?php echo $Book->Firstname?></td>
            <td><?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $Book->picture ).'"/>';?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Book->price?></td>
            <td><?php echo $Book->availabilty?></td>
             <td><?php echo $Book->name?></td>
         </tr>
         <?php
         }
          ?>
      </table>

   </body>
</html>
```

the routes

```
Route::post('searchingg','BookSearchController@searchbook');

Route::get('searchbook', function () {
    return view('book-search');
});
```

Comment: dude you need to learn laravel first
this is not the way we use laravel here is a wonderful free tutorial
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller should be responsible to return data to the client.

Change your model to return the resultset from the database:

```
public function searchbooks(Request $request){

  $query = $request->get('query');
  $Books = DB::table('bookuser')->Join('users', 'bookuser.userID', '=','users.id')->Join('book', 'bookuser.bookID','=','book.ID')->select('Firstname','picture','price','availabilty','name')->where('name','like','%'. $query. '%')->get();

    return $Books;

}
```

and your controller:

```
public function searchbook(Request $request){
    $reader = new Book_Search;
    $Books = $reader->searchbooks($request);
    $query = $request->query;

    return view('book_search', compact('Books', 'query'));
}
```